# Installing all Visual Studio 2015 product updates at once

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to install all available product updates using the 'modify' option under Programs and Features?

[image]

When I launch Visual Studio, it lists 2 product updates. If I click on each update it launches the same UI but with different information (and also prompts you to close Visual Studio).

[image]

[image]

If I look in Task Manager, I can see the command-line for the second update is

```
"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a47f6f59-0768-45af-8aa6-10ad157a603e}\vs_enterprise.exe"  /filterfeatureselectiontree AppInsightsToolsVisualStudioHidden;AppInsightsToolsVSWinExpressHidden;AppInsightsToolsVWDExpressHidden /installselectableitems AppInsightsToolsVisualStudioHidden;AppInsightsToolsVSWinExpressHidden;AppInsightsToolsVWDExpressHidden /ChainingPackage VSNotificationHub
```

Which makes me wonder if it is possible to launch the installer with appropriate arguments to allow it to update any pending components.

Comment: I think an answer might involve parsing the Atom feed mentioned in Tim Sneath's blog post http://timsneath.com/visual-studio-2015-installation-options/